# UWP: What is the recommendation for the size of the logo in the splash screen?

Tags: uwp

The splash screen documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/add-a-splash-screen says the splash screen image is not stretched, remains centered so it can be smaller than the window:

> Important  The splash screen image you choose must be 620 x 300 pixels
> using a 1x scaling factor. Also, when designing your splash screen,
> note that it is smaller than the screen, and centered. It does not
> fill the screen like a splash screen for a Windows Phone Store app
> does.

But what about the size of the actual representation you put in the image?

For example, an app logo. What is the size percentage which the logo should have in respect to the size of the splash screen image? Any recommendations?

Also, **2nd question:**  I don't quite understand why Windows wants exact splash screen sizes of 2480 x 1200, 1240 x 600, 930 x 450, 775 x 375 and 620 x 300 since the splash screen image is centered anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the size percentage which the logo should have in respect to the size of the splash screen image? Any recommendations?

This depends on how you design your app logo. You could make the logo in any size you want. When the splash screen is displayed, only the size of the background changes to compensate for a variety of screen sizes. Your image always remains intact.

> I don't quite understand why Windows wants exact splash screen sizes of 2480 x 1200, 1240 x 600, 930 x 450, 775 x 375 and 620 x 300 since the splash screen image is centered anyway?

These images with different pixels and scales will be used in different scenarios such as different devices, different scaling settings. That could make your app have a splash screen that adapts to different scenarios.